# How can cypress be made to work with aurelia with github actions and locally?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, aurelia, cypress, github-actions

Ok, so I added cypress to aurelia during my configuration and it worked fine. When I went to set up cypress on github as just a command, I could not get it to recognize puppeteer as a browser. So instead I went and used the official github actions for cypress, and that works

```
      - name: test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v1
        with:
          start: yarn start
          browser: ${{matrix.browser}}
          record: true
        env:
          # pass the Dashboard record key as an environment variable
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
```

however I had to set my `cypress.json` as follows

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
  "fixturesFolder": "test/e2e/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "test/e2e/integration",
  "pluginsFile": "test/e2e/plugins/index.js",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/e2e/screenshots",
  "supportFile": "test/e2e/support/index.js",
  "videosFolder": "test/e2e/videos",
  "projectId": "..."
}
```

and now running `yarn e2e` doesn't work because there's no server stood up, as it's not doing it itself anymore via `cypress.config.js`

```js
const CLIOptions =  require( 'aurelia-cli').CLIOptions;
const aureliaConfig = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const PORT = CLIOptions.getFlagValue('port') || aureliaConfig.platform.port;
const HOST = CLIOptions.getFlagValue('host') || aureliaConfig.platform.host;

module.exports = {
  config: {
    baseUrl: `http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
    fixturesFolder: 'test/e2e/fixtures',
    integrationFolder: 'test/e2e/integration',
    pluginsFile: 'test/e2e/plugins/index.js',
    screenshotsFolder: 'test/e2e/screenshots',
    supportFile: 'test/e2e/support/index.js',
    videosFolder: 'test/e2e/videos'
  }
};
```

how can I make it so that `yarn e2e` works as it previously did, and have it working on github?(I don't care which side of the equation is changed)

here's `yarn e2e` not sure what the au is doing under the hood.

```
    "e2e": "au cypress",
```

Comment: The actions connected to the "au" command are defined in the aurelia_project/tasks folder by default.

Next, we run the following command to start all:
`yarn cypress run`

Comment: To finish my comment:

Since we use typescript, we added the webpack-preprocessor as  plugin to cypress, as described [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/preprocessors__typescript-webpack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this, create a `test/e2e/cypress-config.json`

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
  "fixturesFolder": "test/e2e/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "test/e2e/integration",
  "pluginsFile": "test/e2e/plugins/index.js",
  "screenshotsFolder": "test/e2e/screenshots",
  "supportFile": "test/e2e/support/index.js",
  "videosFolder": "test/e2e/videos",
  "projectId": "1234"
}
```

, and then setup the github action like this.

```
      - name: test
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v1
        with:
          config-file: tests/e2e/cypress-config.json
          start: yarn start
          browser: ${{matrix.browser}}
          record: true
        env:
          # pass the Dashboard record key as an environment variable
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
```

the path doesn't matter, just that you configure the same one. Just make sure it doesn't overlap with what aurelia wants.